# Not able to Perform DrillDown operation with python cubes over postgres db

Tags: python, postgresql, olap-cube

I am trying to  run Python cubes OLAP server over my sample postgresql database.

I have only one table called purachse and it has 4 fields.

Purchase

purchase_id | purchase_date | quantity | unit_price | total_cost

My model.json file is as shown below

```
{
"dimensions": [

    {"name":"purchase_id"},
    {"name":"purchase_date"}
],
"cubes": [
    {
        "name": "purachse",
        "dimensions": ["purchase_id","purchase_date"],
        "measures": [{"name":"quantity", "label":"quantity"},{"name":"total_cost","label":"total_cost"}],
        "aggregates": [
                {
                    "name": "quantity",
                    "function": "sum",
                    "measure": "quantity"
                },
                {
                    "name":"total_cost",
                    "function":"sum",
                    "measure":"total_cost"
                },
                {
                    "name": "record_count",
                    "function": "count"
                }

            ]
    }

]
```

}

And am able to perform all operations like aggregate,cut etc over this server.
But when am trying to drilldown with any of the fileds it is showing internal server error.
And when i tried the same db with sqlite it worked pretty well including the drilldown.
I couldn't figure out where the problem is . I am a newbie to python cubes and postgresql
kindly help.

Am also attaching the .ini file here. The log file is not being generated and it makes hard to track the issue.

```
[server]
host: 0.0.0.0 
port: 5000
reload: yes
log_level: debug
log: /var/log/cubes.log
prettyprint: yes
backend: sql
[datastore]
type: sql
url: postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/purchase

schema: purchase
debug: true

[models]
path: model_postgres.json
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Have you tried it in a fresh virtualenv with actual SQLAlchemy and Cubes from the github master?

Comment: Do you still have this issue? If yes, can you run slicer with `--debug` argument as in `slicer serve --debug slicer.ini` and paste the exception here, please?

Comment: @Stiivi 'ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) column "purchase.purchase_date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT purchase.purchase.purchase_date AS purchase_date, ...
               ^
 'SELECT purchase.purchase.purchase_date AS purchase_date, sum(purchase.purchase.quantity) AS quantity, sum(purchase.purchase.total_cost) AS total_cost, count(%(param_1)s) AS record_count, sum(purchase.purchase.quantity) AS quantity_sum, sum(purchase.purchase.total_cost) AS total_cost_sum \nFROM purchase.purchase' {'param_1': 1}' is the exception i got

Comment: @Stiivi the generated query doesn't have group by clause in it that is the error i could find. I haven't tried since then. Don't know the condition with latest versions